# Formato petición SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, net

Estoy intentando montar un servicio web SOAP para usar con el cobro de recibos de Correos.

Según la documentación, hay que montar un servicio web con dos métodos que devuelvan cierta información. Los he montado sin problema, pero no consigo que se adecuen al formato del ejemplo.

Tengo que decir que hace años que no hacía servicios SOAP (desde Net 2.0) porque hace mucho que pasé a servicios REST, así que si veis alguna tontería me la tendréis que perdonar.

La petición de ejemplo que viene en la documentación (la buena) es esta:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pag="http://pagorecibos.pagosrecibos.com/"> 
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <pag:obtenerImporte>
            <referencia>040</referencia>
        </pag:obtenerImporte>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

La que esta generando mi servicio web es esta:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <obtenerImporte xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <referencia>string</referencia>
    </obtenerImporte>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

El código de mi servicio es este:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string ObtenerImporte(ObtenerImporte obtenerImporte)
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string RealizarPago(RealizarPago realizarPago)
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }

}
```

Clase (solo pongo una, porque la otra es igual):

```
public class ObtenerImporte
{
    [XmlElement("referencia")]
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
}
```

Obviamente fallan los namespace y el prefijo del nodo "obtenerImporte", pero no soy capaz de resolverlo.

Comentar que estoy usando VS2017 Community Edition y he creado el proyecto usando la plantilla que viene como "Servicio Web ASP.NET".

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto!!!. Añadiendo y quitando algunas cosas ha funcionado. La manera correcta de definir el servicio es así:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://pagorecibos.pagosrecibos.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string ObtenerImporte(ObtenerImporte obtenerImporte)
    {
        return "Obtener Importe";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string RealizarPago(RealizarPago realizarPago)
    {
        return "Realizar Pago";
    }
}
```

Lo dejo aquí por si alguien más le puede venir bien.

Comment: échale una mirada a este artículo para ver cúal es la mejor manera de responder la pregunta que ha hecho uno mismo. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301/c%C3%B3mo-respondo-mi-propia-pregunta